# Add list to a specific column of DataTable

Tags: vb.net, uipath

I'm new to uipath and working with list and DataTable. 
I do know how to add data in DataTable from same list using Add Data Row activity in for each activity. But I don't know how to add data in DataTable from two different lists. Because in for each activity you have to give name of one list to iterate.
I really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: I've never used UiPath - never even heard of it - but a quick look at the documentation indicates that a `ForEachRow` activity performs an action for each row in the `DataTable`.  Why can't that action be getting values from two lists and storing them in two fields of the current row?  It looks as though you have access to the index of the current row so you would use that to index the two lists to get the values.

Comment: Why not iterate over the first list then over the second?

Comment: We need a bit more details. What should happen with the list? Should list A turn into the first column, and list B to the second one? Can you make sure that they'll always have the same number of items, and if not, what should happen?

Answer (score 0):

Use For Each activity, but iterate over Enumerable.Range(0,yourList1.Length-1). This gives you enumerable of numbers, from 0 to max item on your list. Than when in For Each part, you add row, and you call value from yourList1(i)

ForEach i in Enumerable.Range(0,yourList1.Length-1)
   dt.addrow(yourList1(i),yourList2(i))
next i

Now, the issue here is, whether both of your lists are the same length, to not to run in out of boundaries error, and whether corresponding items are on the same index(i)

Even better solution is to have datatable where in one column you store values of list1 in other column list2
Or to have List(of array) where array has 2 members, one coming from list1, and second one coming from list2.